# Close window and open another on PyQt without finishing the execution

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to close a window using PyQt and open another, but this is not happening. Someone could help me?

Here is what I am doing basically:

```
class App(QtGui.QMainWindow, MainWindow.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, privilegio, db):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.get_thread = None
        self.db = db
        self.privilegio = privilegio

class Login(QtGui.QMainWindow, LoginWindow.Ui_McDonalds):

    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.verify)
        self.db = None
        self.db_connection = False
        self.connect_db()


def login():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form_login = Login()
    form_login.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    login()

if password == result[0][0]:
    main(result[0][1], self.db)
```

Comment: You sure don't want to do `sys.exit`

Comment: @m0dem exactly, but if I don't put this line, the window will not open...

Answer (score 0):

you can connect the close event (button.clicked or some else) of the first window to `window2.show`

by putting before `sys.exit(app.exec_())`

```
window1.rejected.connect(window2.show)
```

or in your first window `__init__`

```
self.rejected.connect(window2.show)
```

or

```
self.my_button.clicked.connect(window2.show)
```

Comment: thank you, I've managed to solve the problem, by declaring the window before the sys.exit().